# Grub problems while installing ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, grub

I installed ubuntu,but when I restarted my machine it shows:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
grub rescue>
```

I tried running boot-repair from live cd
here is the dump of that: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1411870/

Let me know if someone has done this before

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found
i am sure this will work. At least it always does work for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `boot` partition in something else mode. In mount point type `/boot/efi` and select `FAT32` as the partition type. Allocate around 500MB and this is the solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter with this several times, I guess you didn't leave a room for `/boot`

My solution is that you should reinstall it (while you should rewrite the U disk or you will just goto the same place)
I didn't know how to rescue the grub, I think it's kind of complex, so just reinstall it and it won't take much time, and remember leave a room `/boot`
not a big deal,take it easy and   hope that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

To install grub ubuntu

1-**cd live ubuntu**

select install ubuntu without

2-**open terminal**

```
3-
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/root-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
boot-repair
```